# How can I convert flash armature (ik) animation to frame-by-frame animation with jsfl

Tags: flash, jsfl, inverse-kinematics

My objective is to paste together several ( a lot, actually ) armature animations, each in a separate symbol. I have no idea how to do it, armature layers are a bit... strange. So i see only one solution: convert it to a regular layer.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something weird with converting to frame-by-frame from jsfl. If you choose 'Convert to Frame By Frame' animation from the IDE, then you look in the History Panel(F10), Timeline's convertToKeyframes() function is used. 
It doesn't seem to do the same thing when you call it from JSFL though. You can see this if you Undo, then select that step from the History Panel and hit Replay.

You could create a movieclip for each armature though.

```
var doc      = fl.getDocumentDOM();
var timeline = doc.getTimeline();

//convert to keyframes, doesn't work the same way as 'Convert to Frame by Frame Animation' option from the IDE
//timeline.convertToKeyframes();

//make a movieclip for the selected armature
doc.convertToSymbol('movie clip', 'armatureName', 'top left');
```

I didn't undestand what you mean by 'paste together' though. Do you mean joining the armatures animation one after another ?